# Iterating same function over multiple object paramaters - error after first iteration

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```js
function listIngredArray(recipe) {
    let output = '<ul>'
    for (let i = 0; i < recipe.ingredients.length; i++) {
        output += `<li>${recipe.ingredients[i][1]}${findIngredient(shoppingList, recipe.ingredients[i][0], "measure")}: <span class="float-right">${findIngredient(shoppingList, recipe.ingredients[i][0], "name")}</span></li>`
    }
    return output
}

function findIngredient(list, search, paramater) {
    for (type in list) {
        for (ingredient in list[type]) {
            if (ingredient === search) {
                return list[type][ingredient][paramater]
            }
        }
    }
    return "not found"
}
```

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will run output the results of a function "recipeGen()" multiple times for each member of an object.
The code I have written can output the name of each member of the object I want to effect if told to log to console, but will only run the desired function once before giving me an "uncaught typeError"
How can I change this so that my code outputs "recipeGen()" for every sub member of "recipes"?

Thanks in advance for any help.

p.s. the recipes object I am using is larger than the one posted here but in exactly the same format all the way through. In current state my code will output recipeGen() for the first member "roastRosemaryPotatoes" and give the error when attempting to run the function for the next object.

p.p.s I have also tried using 2 x for/in loops with the same result, hence the Object.keys usage in the second half of function

```js
function outputAllRecipes() {
  for (type in recipes) {
    console.log(type)
    let recipeArray = Object.keys(recipes[type])
    console.log(recipeArray)
    for (let i = 0; i < recipeArray.length; i++) {
      recipeGen(recipes[type][recipeArray[i]])
    }
  }
}

function recipeGen(recipe) {
  let output = `<div class="recipe-box">`
  output += `<h3>${recipe.name}</h3>`
  output += `<div class="ingredient-list"><h4>Ingredients:</h4>`
  output += `</div>`
  output += `<h4>Method:</h4>`
  output += recipe.method + `</div>`
  console.log(output)
  return output
}

let recipes = {
  side: {
    roastRosemaryPotatoes: {
      name: "Roast Rosemary Potatoes",
      serves: 2,
      ingredients: [
        ['potato', 3],
        ['rosemary', 1],
        ['oliveOil', 30],
        ['saltPepper', 0]
      ],
      method: `<ol>
                    <li> Preheat oven to 180 degrees</li>
                    <li> Cut potatoes in to bite sized chunks</li>
                    <li> In a large bowl, toss the potatoes, rosemary, salt and pepper untill evenly coated</li>
                    <li> Roast at 180 for ~20 minutes, then turn oven up to 220 degrees and roast for a further 15 - 20 minutes</li>
                    <li> Serve</li>
                    </ol>`
    },
    mashedPotAndsweetPotato: {
      name: "Mashed Potato and Sweet Potato",
      serves: 2,
      ingredients: [
        ['potato', 2],
        ['sweetPotato', 1],
        ['butter', 25],
        ['saltPepper', 2]
      ],
      method: `<ol>
                    <li> Roughly dice the potato and steam in a steamer until tender (15 - 20 minutes)</li>
                    <li> In a large bowl, add the potatoes, butter and salt and pepper to the potatoes and mash with a potato masher in to a puree.
                    (if you do not have a potato masher, you can use a fork, or a wooden spoon but the result will be quite lumpy. I like potatoes this way but YMMV)</li>
                    <li> Serve</li>
                    </ol>`
    }
  }
}

outputAllRecipes()
```

Comment: You've missed out the `listIngredArray` function from your code.

Comment: Your code currently fails because there is no `listIngredArray(recipe)` function. Can you please remove that call (replace it with something simple to mock it) and then add a call to `outputAllRecipes()` at the end of your snippet? Thanks.

Comment: After removing the call to listIngredArray, the code now works as intendeed on Stackoverflow but not in my original code.

Comment: UPDATE: I have made more progress. Removing the call to listIngredArray() causes the function to work correctly, so I guess this means something in the listIngredArray() is causing the TypeError. Apologies for noob question, but everyone has to learn somewhere and googling yielded me nothing. I'll add the offending functions to the code snippet above incase anyone can help pinpoint what is causing the issue here. Thanks for the help :)